# retreive values from database and store it as session variable

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I have created a form for payment in html. The values in the form are added automaticaly usng session. when the user logs in, the values are added using the user infromation. my html is below:

```html
<table>
    <form name="postForm" action="form_process.php" method="POST" >
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid=time().rand(1000,99999); ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>amount</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['amount']; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>firstname</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>phone</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['phone']; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>productinfo</td><td><input type="text" name="productinfo" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['productinfo']; ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="surl" value="success.php" size="64" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="furl" value="fail.php" size="64" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" /></td><td><input type="reset" /></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

in the login page, i have stored the session as below:

```html
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
$user_email=$_POST['email'];
$user_pass=$_POST['pass'];

$check_user="select * from users WHERE user_email='$user_email'AND user_pass='$user_pass'";

$run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);

if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0)
{
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($run);


$_SESSION['email']=$user_email;

$_SESSION['access']=$result['access'];


//here session is used and value of $user_email store in $_SESSION.
echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";

}
else
{
echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
}
}

?>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.css">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/imageedit_2_5125240109.gif"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/appointment_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- //for bootstrap working -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<style>
.login-panel {
margin-top: 150px;
}
</style>

<body>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<div class="login-panel panel panel-success">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">Sign In</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<form role="form" method="post" action="login.php">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group" >
<input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass" type="password" value="">
</div>


<input type="submit" value="login" name="login" >

<!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
<!-- <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a> -->
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

the user email is correctly inputted in the form , but the mobile number and other details are not being added into the form. i tried string them as variables like above, but its not displaying. i think i need to fetch the details from database. can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Did you check what `$result` is containing?

Comment: i have tried with results also but its showing undefined index

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection.  Please learn how to use prepared statements in your queries.  https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: Did you try `echo $result[0]['access']`?

Comment: use `print_r($result);` just below `$result=mysqli_fetch_array($run);` to get the data which is stored. user `print_r(error_get_last());` just below it to see if there is any error in connection or something.

Comment: @PrashantRajpoot nothing is displaying while printing

Comment: `print_r($result);` is not giving any data? have you tried `print_r(error_get_last());`? Atleast you will get the error.

Comment: @PrashantRajpoot yes nothing displaying

Comment: If `print_r($result);` is not displaying anything it means the query is returning an empty result.

Comment: then check your query first `if(!$run){ echo mysqli_error($dbcon);}`. Use this just above `$result=mysqli_fetch_array($run);`

Comment: its just showing email or password is incorect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done alot of research and finally go the answer myself.

i used the $_SESSION and the select query to get the information of the current user from the database. and used the while loop to put them in variable.
the updated code is below:

```html
<div  class="sing"><?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['email'] == true) {
  echo " &nbsp Welcome  " . $_SESSION['email'] ;
echo "<div style='float: right;'><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>&nbsp</div>";
} else {

}


?>
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <h2>Payment Gateway Testing Sample</h2>
  <h3>Fill the form and submit it for starting the transaction...</h3>
 </div>

<div>



  <?php

  include("config.php");


$user_email=$_SESSION['email'];
  $check_user="select * from users WHERE user_email='$user_email'";

  $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);

while($row = $run->fetch_assoc())
{

 $user_name=$row['user_name'];
 $user_mobile=$row['user_mobile'];

}
  //here session is used and value of $user_email store in $_SESSION.




  ?>


<table>
 <form name="postForm" action="form_process.php" method="POST" >
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid=time().rand(1000,99999); ?>" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>amount</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" value="" /></td></tr>



 <tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $user_name; ?>" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>phone</td><td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $user_mobile; ?>" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>productinfo</td><td><input type="text" name="productinfo" value="" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="surl" value="success.php" size="64" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="furl" value="fail.php" size="64" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="submit" /></td><td><input type="reset" /></td></tr>
 </form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```